# Filter error messages from build output

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm having a hard time to quickly fix syntax errors with Visual Studio 2010 because usually the build output consists of lots and lots of warnings and maybe one or two error messages. The errors are hidden like the proverbial needle in the haystack.

Now I don't want to ignore the warnings, but the errors are more important. Is there a setting/method/trick/... in Visual Studio 2010 to filter only the error messages from the build output? Perhaps one can sort the build output according to warnings an errors. If so, how?

Comment: On the errors / warning list, you just need to click on errors/warnings to hide/show them in the pane...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all in the image... essentially, click on the type of messages you want to view/hide in the Errors list to toggle them from visible to hidden and back again...

[image: Click Here to hide the warnings... click again to unhide]

Comment: Thanks. You could have told me "Use the error list, not the output window, stupid!" ;-)

Comment: @chessweb: it's one of those things that takes ages to find, then suddenly you forget ever using anything else... or at least that's how it was with me :)